# How to access index variable in <display:table tag similar to varStatus in <c:forEach

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, displaytag

I need to access the index for every row in a displaytag table.
Similar to 
By the way, I am using displaytag 1.2 in JSP. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote from [the documentation](http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/displaytag/tagreference.html):

> uid  - Unique id used to identify this table. The object representing the current row is also added to the pageContext under this name, so that you can refer to it in column bodies using ${uid}. **You can also use uid_rowNum to refer to the current row number.**

(emphasis mine)